# Motor Driver Deadtime, on-switching-time and off-switching-time

Tags: motor, driver

I have the following motor driver (DRV8320):
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8320.pdf?ts=1616576087660&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8320

Since I want to implement the deadtime compensation, I need to know what the deadtime, the on-switching time and the off switching time are, according to:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4863.pdf

Since I use the hardware variant, the deadtime is constant at 100ns, but what are the on-switching time and off-switching time? I use the Idrive in the 60/120mA mode (60mA drive, 120mA sink) and the MOSFET types are BSC0702LSATMA1 (https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_BSC0702LS_DataSheet-1770891.pdf) with a gate charge of maximum 11nC.

Can I say, that t_on = 11nC/60mA=180ns and t_off = 11nC/120mA = 90ns?

If so, the deadtime seems pretty neglictable, right?

Comment: You are probably better off measuring it with an oscilloscope. You also have the MCU switch time and aliasing, current allowance, line inductance, and all sorts of stuff to consider.

Comment: Switching times are interface driver and load dependent so this cannot be answered as it stands.

Comment: Ok, I will measure with the Osci. If it is load dependet, is there a way to choose a static compensation to at least improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

That’s not the only variable

At maximum voltage gain the 1% setting time is 1200 ns so the switching time might be 1/10 th of this or 120 ns and 100 ns deadtime will raise the driver temperature from shootthru. So choosing a lower Av setting is wise.

The other variable is the DCR of inductance and loop resistance of DCR + Ron when the other driver is switching off where T=L/R changes dynamically so the heat loss is the RMS product of that Vds(t) * I(t) * L/R as well x duty factor. A more lossy circuit is better dampened and switches faster. These are trade offs for a fixed deadtime that may be insufficient.

Comment: Ok, you are right, so I need to increase the smart gate capability to 120mA/240mA (source/sink), that should be enough.

Comment: IDK, I used max current  with slew rate control, read about that

Comment: Mhh ok, I had a ringing problem at the maximum current, that's why I reduced it. The ringing leaded even to destruction of the gate driver.

Comment: That depends on slew rate control L/R etc

Comment: I have another strange phenomena, maybe you know what could be a reason for this: The motor turns more noisy in one direction (more current peaks to keep a velocity) and more overshoot at acceleration. The electrical angle is correctly set (checked with an osci) and a SW bug in the FOC is excluded, since when I change the motor phase U and V, the motor turns better in the opposit direction as before. So can this also be a problem related to deadtime or do you have another idea, what could cause this?

Comment: The FOC vectors need to invert as well as the driver phase pair in order to control equal current and torque in either direction, but there may be timing  differences from rise or fall time., got a scope to check V, I? On each phase?

Comment: I created a new question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/555155/foc-performance-direction-dependent