# FOC performance direction dependent

Tags: motor

I'm struggling with a FOC setup, which turns the motor better in one direction than the other and I really don't know, what I could do, to solve this problem, since nothing seems to change it.

[image]

You can see, that one direction has higher Id current spikes (depcited in red). So what I tried so far:

- My first tought was an encoder alignement problem (magnetic absolute encoder), but this seems not to be the case, I can aligne the encoder on the back of the motor as I want, the good direction stays the same until I manually change the phases of the motor
- Also the electrical angle is fine, I evaluated in manually with an oscilloscope and the performance of the good direction never gets worse than the bad direction when I adjust the electrical offset, up to extrem values.
- Also an encoder delay is not the case, I tried also to compensate for the delay, up to extrem values, but the good direction never got worse than the bad direction.

From the current measurements, there seems a big difference when the motor is unloaded at +-800rpm. I measured directly the U-phase current and it seems, something goes wrong there, but I cannot see at the moment, what that could cause. Under load, the motor works quit well and the phase current looks the same in both directions.

Good direction U-phase current:
[image]

Bad direction U-phase current:
[image]

Here is also the SVPWM implementation, maybe here is something wrong:

```
float t1;
float t2;

/********************************/
/* Check for the correct sector */
/********************************/
if(foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV >= 0.0f)
{
    if(foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV >= 0.0f)
    {
        if(ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV > foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV)
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(-ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV > foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV)
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 2;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if(foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV >= 0.0f)
    {
        if(-ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV > foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV)
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 6;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV > foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV)
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            foc.svpwm.sector = 5;
        }
    }
}

/************************************************/
/* Calculate the sector depending SVPWM timings */
/************************************************/
switch (foc.svpwm.sector)
{
    case 1:
        t1 = foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV - ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;
        t2 = TWO_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;

        /********************************/
        /* Calculate the PWM Timings    */
        /********************************/
        foc.svpwm.tU_s = (1.0f - t1 - t2) * 0.5f;
        foc.svpwm.tV_s = foc.svpwm.tU_s + t1;
        foc.svpwm.tW_s = foc.svpwm.tV_s + t2;
        break;
    case 2:
        t1 = foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV + ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;
        t2 = -foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV + ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;

        /********************************/
        /* Calculate the PWM Timings    */
        /********************************/
        foc.svpwm.tV_s = (1.0f - t1 - t2) * 0.5f;
        foc.svpwm.tU_s = foc.svpwm.tV_s + t2;
        foc.svpwm.tW_s = foc.svpwm.tU_s + t1;
        break;
    case 3:
        t1 = TWO_BY_SQRT3 *foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;
        t2 = - foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV - ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;

        /********************************/
        /* Calculate the PWM Timings    */
        /********************************/
        foc.svpwm.tV_s = (1.0f - t1 - t2) * 0.5f;
        foc.svpwm.tW_s = foc.svpwm.tV_s + t1;
        foc.svpwm.tU_s = foc.svpwm.tW_s + t2;
        break;
    case 4:
        t1 = -foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV + ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;
        t2 = -TWO_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;

        /********************************/
        /* Calculate the PWM Timings    */
        /********************************/
        foc.svpwm.tW_s = (1.0f - t1 - t2) * 0.5f;
        foc.svpwm.tV_s = foc.svpwm.tW_s + t2;
        foc.svpwm.tU_s = foc.svpwm.tV_s + t1;
        break;
    case 5:
        t1 = -foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV - ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;
        t2 = foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV - ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;

        /********************************/
        /* Calculate the PWM Timings    */
        /********************************/
        foc.svpwm.tW_s = (1.0f - t1 - t2) * 0.5f;
        foc.svpwm.tU_s = foc.svpwm.tW_s + t1;
        foc.svpwm.tV_s = foc.svpwm.tU_s + t2;
        break;
    case 6:
        t1 = -TWO_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;
        t2 = foc.ctrl.valpha_norm_mV + ONE_BY_SQRT3 * foc.ctrl.vbeta_norm_mV;

        /********************************/
        /* Calculate the PWM Timings    */
        /********************************/
        foc.svpwm.tU_s = (1.0f - t1 - t2) * 0.5f;
        foc.svpwm.tW_s = foc.svpwm.tU_s + t2;
        foc.svpwm.tV_s = foc.svpwm.tW_s + t1;
        break;

    default:
        return API_MCL_FOC_ERROR_SVPWM_FAILED;
        break;
}
```

Comment: you sure you got your rotor aligned correctly?

Comment: Yes, I did also manually adjust the offset around the measured offset and the phenomena still occured the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR timing

There are <s>8</s> 6 combinations of 3 phase vector control

ABC
ACB
BCA
BAC
CAB
CBA

The correct two vectors must be swapped to match the independent phase reversal for 2 motor phases.

Only 1 sequence is correct in each direction.

Your bad direction **may** have the wrong combination.

I verified this on a 3ph 100 W fan recently which I modified to be reversible vbl. speed 4600 CFM (powered by 120Vac to 70Vdc). AS luck would have it I found the right connections on the last try, albeit there were Hall sensors. One bad combination reacted just like your plots appear.

**(with a lack of DC RMS in  1 phase.)**

Oh well justa  guess.

To explore further, increase the time resolution on plots and examine acceleration and steady RPM in each direction.  Or if you can, plot the 3 phase vectors as a **L**issejou plot.  (Another guess)

### Anecdotal

Glad you got it working.
I've never tried FOC but here is a Webinar Zoom call **today** 1pm EST[from Powersimtech](https://powersimtech.com/resources/webinars/) on FOC and high performance PMSM motors. for all who wish to attend free.

### More Anecdotal FWIW to others

> 3 Ph motor reversal for attic roof vent remote-controlled forced air ventilation.

I've never tried FOC, but I reverse engineered a great Hall sensor design with a non-isolated 100W 4600 CFM fan, with FET cooling of course forced air cooling. Very quiet, smooth low acceleration vbl. speed pot which I intend to remote control and power by a weather sensor to the STM32 chip with a bridge controller to 6 FETs for hot day attic forced air ventilation with a 14" fan under a 12" square roof chimney vent.

Photos to follow

Host uC= STM32   They sanded off the most interesting IC part numbers, but I was still able to read them.

Drivers powered by line 120VAC to 75DC non-isolated to 3 pronged 14" Fan 4600 CFM
Pre-driver 3ph 100W fan

[image]
425/400 ns 3pH full bridge MOS controller $1 from FORTIOR chips.

https://lcsc.com/product-detail/MOS-Drivers_Fortior-Tech-FD6536S_C97682.html  (Detailed specs only to volume buyers)

My electrical mods to reverse fan direction.
[image]
[image]
[image]
STM8S 903K3T6 uC and FORTIER FD6536S MOS bridge controller
[image]

Typical 3 Ph signals with PWM speed control. and great smooth acceleration so no surge currents controlled from STM32 firmware.

[image]

Fortier MOS controller nicer than this std. design[image]

[image]

Nice design tools
[image]

Comment: Interesting, but does this really only lead to a "little bit" more noise in the Id vector? The motor seems to turn in both directions pretty good, as far as I know, an incorrect phase pair would lead to much worse effect such as uncontrollable. I will try each combination and give the result here. There should be only 6 combination of ABC, right?

Comment: I tried all 6 combinations, but this seems not to solve the problem

Comment: ok try XY plots and Z if you have it for ABC combos

Comment: Ok, finally it was indeed that, there seems to be two working configurations, but one is noisier in one direction, thank you very much, was looking for this problem for month